# font awesome icon rendering then disappearing

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I'm building a personal website, https://stark-ridge-41061.herokuapp.com.
There are several icons for GitHub, SO, etc. One of the icons is for linkedin, but for some reason, the linked in icon shows up for a split second then disappears, and only in Chrome.  I'm not sure if it's important, but when the page renders in Chrome my fa-indeed element does not have a ::before tag like all my other fa-icons.

I have tested it in Firefox and all the icons shows up correctly. What is wrong with my code currently to make it behave this way in Chrome, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: In your code excerpt, the lines are truncated, so we can't see enough code to jusge

Comment: They are behaving themselves on your website in Chrome and Edge. Looks OK on the source code

Comment: FYI - I'm using IE11 (only thing I can use at work, and I'm at work) and only your Quora icon is showing up.

Comment: @amallard that is most likely due to a firewall.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because of Adblock or some sort of tracker blocker. I found out using my console. Better rename the fa-linkedin class to avoid this problem.

```
::content .essb-fans-twitter, ::content .essb-fans-youtube, ::content .essb-mobile-sharepoint, ::content .essb_bottombar, ::content .essb_item, ::content .essb_link_pinterest, ::content .essb_link_twitter, ::content .essb_links_list, ::content .essb_share, ::content .essbfc-container, ::content .essbfc-facebook, ::content .essbfc-instagram, ::content .essbis-hover-overlay, ::content .et-social-google-plus, ::content .et-social-icon, ::content .et-social-icons, ::content .et_social_facebook, ::content .et_social_flyin, ::content .et_social_follow, ::content .et_social_icons_container, ::content .et_social_inline, ::content .et_social_networks, ::content .et_social_pinterest, ::content .et_social_popup, ::content .et_social_sidebar_networks, ::content .et_social_twitter, ::content .etsocialmediahyperlink, ::content .event-share-center, ::content .event-social-box, ::content .eventShare, ::content .ew-social-icons, ::content .expand-share, ::content .expanded_story_socialmedia, ::content .extra-social, ::content .extra-social-links, ::content .extreme-share, ::content .eyebrow-share-widget, ::content .f-social, ::content .f-social-link, ::content .fBsocial, ::content .fButtonLarge, ::content .f_social, ::content .fa-facebook, ::content .fa-facebook-f, ::content .fa-facebook-square, ::content .fa-fb, ::content .fa-flickr, ::content .fa-google, ::content .fa-google-plus, ::content .fa-google-plus-square, ::content .fa-instagram, ::content .fa-linkedin, ::content .fa-linkedin-square, ::content .fa-pinterest, ::content .fa-pinterest-p, ::content .fa-pinterest-square, ::content .fa-reddit, ::content .fa-reddit-square, ::content .fa-share-alt, ::content .fa-share-square-o, ::content .fa-soundcloud, ::content .fa-tumblr, ::content .fa-tumblr-square, ::content .fa-twit, ::content .fa-twitter, ::content .fa-twitter-square, ::content .fa-vine, ::content .fa-youtube, ::content .fa-youtube-play, ::content .fa-youtube-square, ::content .faceBookButton, ::content .faceBookShareContainer, ::content .facebook-24x24, ::content .facebook-activity, ::content .facebook-badge, ::content .facebook-banner, ::content .facebook-banner-wrapper, ::content .facebook-bar, ::content .facebook-big-share, ::content .facebook-block, ::content .facebook-box, ::content .facebook-box-widget, ::content .facebook-broadcasting-widget, ::content .facebook-btn, ::content .facebook-button, ::content .facebook-button-link, ::content .facebook-circle, ::content .facebook-connect-dialog, ::content .facebook-container, ::content .facebook-count-single, ::content .facebook-facepile, ::content .facebook-fans, ::content .facebook-flyout, ::content .facebook-follow, ::content .facebook-follow-button, ::content .facebook-footer, ::content .facebook-ft, ::content .facebook-hover-horizontal, ::content .facebook-icon, ::content .facebook-icon-small, ::content .facebook-image, ::content .facebook-inner, ::content .facebook-like, ::content .facebook-like-bottom, ::content .facebook-like-box, ::content .facebook-like-button-head, ::content .facebook-like-large, ::content .facebook-like-message-holder, ::content .facebook-likebox, ::content .facebook-likebox-promo, ::content .facebook-link, ::content .facebook-menu, ::content .facebook-modal, ::content .facebook-module, ::content .facebook-p, ::content .facebook-recommend, ::content .facebook-right-rail, ::content .facebook-row, ::content .facebook-section, ::content .facebook-share, ::content .facebook-share-bottom, ::content .facebook-share-btn, ::content .facebook-share-button, ::content .facebook-share-link, ::content .facebook-share-story, ::content .facebook-sharer, ::content .facebook-sharetool, ::content .facebook-sidebar, ::content .facebook-sidebar-outer, ::content .facebook-social, ::content .facebook-social-likes, ::content .facebook-top, ::content .facebook-top-button, ::content .facebook-twitter, ::content .facebook-twitter-share, ::content .facebook-twitter-wrap, ::content .facebook-widget, ::content .facebook.icon, ::content .facebook2, ::content .facebookActivity, ::content .facebookBloc_png, ::content .facebookBox, ::content .facebookBtn, ::content .facebookButtonDiv, ::content .facebookConnect, ::content .facebookContainer, ::content .facebookCountDiv, ::content .facebookFanBox, ::content .facebookFeed, ::content .facebookFrame, ::content .facebookGroup, ::content .facebookHomepageBottom, ::content .facebookIcon, ::content .facebookImage, ::content .facebookItem, ::content .facebookLike, ::content .facebookLikeBox, ::content .facebookLikeboxContentContainer, ::content .facebookLink, ::content .facebookOptions, ::content .facebookOuter, ::content .facebookRec, ::content .facebookRecentActivity, ::content .facebookRecommend, ::content .facebookRecommendation, ::content .facebookShare, ::content .facebookShareAlert, ::content .facebookShareIcon, ::content .facebookShareToolsContainer, ::content .facebookSharer, ::content .facebookSite, ::content .facebookSocialIcon, ::content .facebookTwitterIcons, ::content .facebookWidgetry, ::content .facebookWrapperModule, ::content .facebook_24, ::content .facebook_activity, ::content .facebook_badge, ::content .facebook_block, ::content .facebook_box, ::content .facebook_box_sidebar, ::content .facebook_btn, ::content .facebook_button, ::content .facebook_button_bg, ::content .facebook_cont, ::content .facebook_fanbox, ::content .facebook_follower, ::content .facebook_icn, ::content .facebook_icon, ::content .facebook_image, ::content .facebook_indiv_widget, ::content .facebook_large, ::content .facebook_like, ::content .facebook_like_box, ::content .facebook_logo, ::content .facebook_net, ::content .facebook_new, ::content .facebook_plugin_container, ::content .facebook_plugin_parent_block, ::content .facebook_pop {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have though of this. It's pretty obvious now.

Answer (score 0):

I found this can also happen if you have 2 instances of fontawesome on the page. I had a pro version loading once in the footer, and didn't see I had a older free kit loading in the footer.

Answer (score 0):

I could not make out much from the answer from JohannesB, by hit and trial I found my solution to the problem:

Earlier I was using the following js from fontawsome:

I replaced that with the following cdn:

And it worked!!